# java assign property when the value is not null

Tags: java, properties, null

I use java.lang.properties to read config file and assign the config values to class's fields. But I don't want to set all the properties in config file. That means, some fields can have default values and be omitted in config file.
So my code should be something like this:

```
if(properties.getProperty("key")!=null){
    value = properties.getProperty("key");
}
```

But there are so many fields to be coded like this. Is there a way to avoid this boring work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a default value argument instead:

```
value = properties.getProperty("key", <default value>);
```

If the key is not found in this property list, it will use the default value.

P.S. de bene esse, eg. `value = properties.getProperty("key", "blabla, this is default value");`

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of property fields and then iterate through them using a loop and set the values.

```
String[] arr = {"Abc","Def"};
for(String s : arr){
  if(properties.getProperty(s)!=null){
    value = properties.getProperty(s);
  }
}
```

But mind well you will also require some logic to put in for setting different values.

Answer (score 0):

You should model your properties as classes like this:

```
class Prop {
      private String value;
      private String key;
      private String default;
      ...

      public void load(Properties properties) {
         if (properties.getProperty(key)!=null) {
            value = properties.getProperty(key, default);
         }
      }
    }
```

This way you can declare a `Prop` array and initialize it this way:

```
   for (Prop prop: props) {
      prop.load(properties);
   }
```

or better make a static class initialization method like this:

```
static public void loadProperties(Properties properties) {
       for (Prop prop: props) {
          prop.load(properties);
       }
   }
```